# Не срабатывает cursor: pointer при наведении на div

Tags: css, hover, cursor

При наведении на `.file-bg` фоновый цвет меняется, а курсор нет. В чем заключается ошибка?

```css
body {
    color: #394E63;
    font: 20px Calibri;
    text-indent: 15px;
}
.file-button input{
    opacity:0;
}
.file_bg {
    background-color: #777;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file_bg:hover{
  background-color: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.file-button input{
    border: none;
    padding: 6px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.file-button .file_bg{
    background-color: #6B6C6D;
}
.file-button p{
    font-family: '__Open Sans_5';
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-button file_bg">
  <p class="h3">файл</p>
  <input type="file" name="your-file" value="" size="40" class="" placeholder="Файл">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что реально мышь наводится на

```
<input type="file" name="your-file" value="" size="40" class="" placeholder="Файл">
```

который переопределяет курсор. Чтобы это исправить, можно добавить

```
.file-button input{
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #394E63;
  font: 20px Calibri;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.file-button input {
  opacity: 0;
}

.file_bg {
  background-color: #777;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file_bg:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  /* cursor: pointer; /* REMOVE */
}

.file-button input {
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: inherit; /* ADD */
}

.file-button .file_bg {
  background-color: #6B6C6D;
}

.file-button p {
  font-family: '__Open Sans_5';
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-button file_bg">
  <p class="h3">файл</p>
  <input type="file" name="your-file" value="" size="40" class="" placeholder="Файл">
</div>
```

А вообще, надо скрыть этот input и сделать нормально с label'ом:

```css
body {
  color: #394E63;
  font: 20px Calibri;
}

.file-button input {
  display: none;
}

.file_bg {
  background-color: #777;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 253px;
}

.file_bg:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.file-button label {
  font-family: '__Open Sans_5';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer; /* Курсор надо прописывать у самих интерактивных элементов */
}
```

```html
<div class="file-button file_bg">
  <label for="some-file" class="h3">файл</label>
  <input type="file" id="some-file" name="your-file">
</div>
```

Comment: наведи мышь чуть левее от слова файл курсор опять измениться)

Comment: @junior-web-dev, исправил... Вот так и думал, что не надо так с инпутами обращаться)))

Comment: Еще думаю label растянуть бы на всю ширину кнопки) но это уже вопрошаемый думаю и сам смогьот)

Comment: @junior-web-dev, блин.. тот случай, когда написать с нуля было бы проще, чем это допиливать... Исправил.